# Add_settings_field() parameterizing callback?

Tags: options, callbacks

I'm trying to create a rather large and extensive settings page with various options of very similar type.

Since there will be about 20 different fields, and the differences between most of those being simply their ID, I'd like to avoid creating a separate callback for each one.

Is it possible to make a callback with a variable for the settings ID of each of these fields? That way one callback can server various settings fields of the same type.

I've tried using the $args parameter for add_setitngs_feild(), but sadly, it does not work. For example:

```
add_settings_field('name', 'Field Name', array($this, 'fieldCallback'), 'SettingsGrouP', 'SettingsSection', array("settingID!")); 


function fieldCallback($id)
{
    echo "<input id='" . $id . "'/>";//etc, etc
}
```

fieldCallback si being called, but the ID of the input is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last optional `$args` argument the you can pass to [`add_settings_fields()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17710/add-settings-field-parameterizing-callback) is passed to callback. So it seems you can use same callback just fine.

Hope I am right because I just stumbled onto this two minutes ago because of discussion in chat. :)

PS looked through code and it's indeed relatively recent, before ~2.9 arguments weren't passed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I'll check this out immediately.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working, sadly :( I've posted code above in the question

Comment: @Georges Oates Larsen it's passed as single array... tried `var_dump($id);` to check? I didn't get to playing with this today but it's highly interesting topic for me so I will definitely get to testing this later. **edit** I couldn't resist :) quick check and `var_dump()` inside callback shows that argument is passed as part of array just fine.

Comment: Changed the callback to: var_dump($id);, and it still came up blank

Comment: @Georges Oates Larsen I am not sure what the reason it fails for you might be... Are you running current WP version? Also you can try simpler test case first without class and such.

Comment: Oh dear, looks like I'm severely outdated! I checked before, but I misread the version number. Sorry for wasting your time here! Thanks for the answer, marking as correct...

Answer (score 0):

In the last (optional) argument `$args` in `add_settings_field()` function you can use `array('label_for' => 'something')` as it is writen in documentation (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field).

So if you want to pass id of your field use 'label_for' for it :)

Answer (score 0):

The way Wordpress passes arguments to the callback function here is a bit tricky, the callback function receives the whole `$args` array as parameter, so you may want to change the function as following:

```
function fieldCallback(array $args)
{
    echo "<input id='" . $args[0] . "'/>";//etc, etc
}
```

and you leave `add_settings_field` as it is.

Answer (score -2):

```
add_settings_field(
    'name', 
    'Field Name', 
    array($this, 'fieldCallback'), 
    'SettingsGrouP', 
    'SettingsSection',
    $args=array("settingID!")
); 

function fieldCallback($id) {
   `echo "<input id='" . $id[0] . "'/>";`
}
```

OR

what Jacer Omri illustrated

Comment: You should explain what the code does and why it answer the question.