# Callback is not called in add_settings_field() when passed as part of an array, but recognises that it's there. It's passed Class to Class using OOP

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I am building a plugin, I created a new admin page and subpage, and inside that subpage, I want to add some Settings. That's why I'm building them using the Settings API.
I am using Composer and Object-Oriented Programming. I have a folder called SettingsAPI, with the following namespace `namespace Blocks\Pages\SettingsAPI;`
Inside that folder, I have three files: `AddSettings.php`, `Settings.php` and `SettingsLayout.php`. All three of them are correctly connected.   The files have the case-sensitive names of the Classes. `Settings.php` has a Class named `Settings`, and so on.

[image: SettingsAPI Folder Structure]

**Content**

- Some Context to my Structure
- What I have already tried
- What to do?

## Some Context to my Structure

Inside `Settings.php` I have a function that holds a variety of arrays, inside of those arrays are the values I want to use for the Settings API. This means I have arrays that are used for `register_setting()`, `add_settings_section()` and `add_settings_field()`.
Inside `AddSettings.php` I have the three functions just mentioned. Both `register_settings()` and `add_settings_field()` work great. I have problems with `add_settings_field()`.
Inside `SettingsLayout.php` I have a very simple layout for where the form should be printed, which is also shown on the Subpage. Just the inputs are missing.

Inside `AddSettings.php` I used a `foreach()` to loop over the array, if I need to. Which is used for both `register_setting()` and `add_settings_field()`, that's because both of those arrays have arrays inside of them. I'll show some code used for `register_setting()` and the `foreach()`.

### Settings.php

```php
$configs = [
      [ // Icon
        "option_group"    =>    "iw_" . $n,
        "option_name"     =>    "iw_icon_" . $n,
        "args"            =>    $iconConfigs
      ],
      [ // Titel
        "option_group"    =>    "iw_" . $n,
        "option_name"     =>    "iw_title_" . $n,
        "args"            =>    $titleConfigs
      ],
      [ // Beschreibung
        "option_group"    =>    "iw_" . $n,
        "option_name"     =>    "iw_description_" . $n,
        "args"            =>    $descriptionConfigs
      ],
      [ // Farbauswahl
        "option_group"    =>    "iw_" . $n,
        "option_name"     =>    "iw_colour_" . $n,
        "args"            =>    $colourConfigs
      ]
    ];
```

The array above is being passed, alongside the other arrays, to the `AddSettings` Class and the next function that will process them.

```php
$this->add_settings->setForm( $configs, $segments, $inputs )->register();
```

`setForm()` does the following with the arguments.

### AddSettings.php

```php
public  function  setForm(  array  $configs,  array  $segments,  array  $inputs )  {
    $this->settings =  $configs;
    $this->sections =  $segments;
    $this->fields =  $inputs;
    return  $this;
}
```

The variables `$settings`, `$sections` and `$fields` have been created at the beginning of the class as public and empty arrays.

```php
public $settings = array();
public $sections = array();
public $fields = array();
```

Which then gets registered with the following function:

```php
public function functionToAdd()  {
return  $this->registerForm($this->settings,  $this->sections,  $this->fields);
}
```

`registerForm()` hold all the Settings API functions from WP, here is `register_setting()`.

```php
foreach( $this->settings as $setting ) {
      register_setting( $setting["option_group"], $setting["option_name"], isset( $setting["args"] ) ? $setting["args"] : "" );
    }
```

This part works great. It also works with `add_settings_section()`. What *doesn't* work, are the inputs. Which I will present now as well:

### Settings.php

Inside this Class is the function/method `setForm( $n = NULL )`, that's where all the arrays are, like the one I showed above. Right now `$n` has no meaning, but it's going to be a number, so I can loop all over those arrays and settings to create more forms. Whether I keep it at `NULL` or I change it to `1`, has no effect on the end-result, same thing.
Here is the array for the fields.

```php
$inputs =  [
    [
        "id"  =>  "iw_icon_"  .  $n,
        "title"  =>  "Icon Auswahl",
        "callback"  =>  function()  use($n)  {  return  $this->iconInput(  $n );  },
        "page"  =>  "info_kreis_bearbeiten",
        "section"  =>  "iw_item_"  .  $n,
        "args"  =>  [  "label_for"  =>  "iw_icon_"  .  $n ]
    ],
    [
        "id"  =>  "iw_title_"  .  $n,
        "title"  =>  "Titel",
        "callback"  =>  function()  use($n)  {  return  $this->titleInput(  $n );  },
        "page"  =>  "info_kreis_bearbeiten",
        "section"  =>  "iw_item_"  .  $n,
        "args"  =>  [  "label_for"  =>  "iw_title_"  .  $n ]
    ],
    [
        "id"  =>  "iw_description_"  .  $n,
        "title"  =>  "Kurz Beschreibung",
        "callback"  =>  function()  use($n)  {  return  $this->descriptionInput(  $n );  },
        "page"  =>  "info_kreis_bearbeiten",
        "section"  =>  "iw_item_"  .  $n,
        "args"  =>  [  "label_for"  =>  "iw_description_"  .  $n
    ],
    [
        "id"  =>  "iw_colour_"  .  $n,
        "title"  =>  "Farbe auswählen",
        "callback"  =>  function()  use($n)  {  return  $this->colourInput(  $n );  },
        "page"  =>  "info_kreis_bearbeiten",
        "section"  =>  "iw_item_"  .  $n,
        "args"  =>  [ "label_for"  =>  "iw_colour_"  .  $n ]
    ]
];
```

So this is an array with three arrays inside of it. This array has callbacks, and it's the callbacks that do not work at all. No matter where I put them or how I write them, they are not being echo'd.  At the bottom I will list all of the things I  have tried.
Like with the settings arrays, they are allso processed like this:

```php
$this->add_settings->setForm( $configs, $segments, $inputs )->register();
```

### AddSettings.php

And then

```php
public function setForm(array  $configs,  array  $segments,  array  $inputs)  {
    $this->settings =  $configs;
    $this->sections =  $segments;
    $this->fields =  $inputs;
    return  $this;
}
```

and

```php
public function functionToAdd() {
    return  $this->registerForm($this->settings,  $this->sections,  $this->fields );
}
```

Which then gets passed to `registerForm()` with the following function:

```php
foreach(  $this->fields as  $field)  {
    add_settings_field( $field["id"], $field["title"], isset( $field["callback"] ) ? $field["callback"] : "", $field["page"], $field["section"] = 'default', $field["args"] = array() );
}
```

And then nothing. No inputs on my Subpage. Everything *but* the fields are being echo'd.
[image: Form on Subpage]
As you can see, the callback used by the section works and shows me the title and description. But the inputs are missing. To show some context on how I called the callback for the sections, here is the one line with the callback from the section array, inside `Settings.php`:

```php
"callback"  =>  function()  use($n)  {  echo  "<p>Bearbeite hier die Info Nummer "  .  $n .  "</p>";  }
```

And the function `add_settings_section()` inside `AddSettings.php`, no `foreach()` was used for this one:

```php
add_settings_section( $sections["id"],  $sections["title"], isset(  $sections["callback"] )  ?  $sections["callback"]  :  "",  $sections["page"]  );
```

It's being called the same way like the fields. But the fields still do not echo anything. Any before anyone says I am echoing inside the anonymous callback function instead of returning another function:

## What I have already tried

I have tried a few things. One of the first things I tried was to edit the way the callback is written. So instead of a function that returns another function I wrote something simple.

```php
"callback"  =>  function() { echo "Echo this please."; },
```

Didn't work.

```php
"callback"  =>  array( $this, "iconInput" ),
```

Also not working
I also tried

```php
"callback"  =>  $this->iconInput( $n ),
```

Which then called the function and echo'd the inputs, *but* not  in the right position. They were at the very top of the page. And if I loop everything, all inputs will be at the top, with the sections below in the right print order. So that's not the solution either.
What I also tried was to move the callback to `AddSettings.php` and call it like that.

```php
add_settings_field(  $field["id"],  $field["title"],  function()  { return $this->iconInput();  },  $field["page"],  $field["section"]  =  'default',  $field["args"]  = array()  );
```

Didn't work either.
When I tried to just directly write the function in there, like so

```php
add_settings_field(  $field["id"],  $field["title"],  function()  { echo "Please echo this";  },  $field["page"],  $field["section"]  =  'default',  $field["args"]  = array()  );
```

Didn't work either. I also always put `die;` at the end, just to see if it's being called at all, and it has not been. It's like the function doesn't exist.
I have also tried to immediately run the function by adding `()` to it:

```php
add_settings_field( $field["id"], $field["title"], isset( $field["callback"] ) ? $field["callback"]() : "", $field["page"], $field["section"] = 'default', $field["args"] = array() );
```

Same result like earlier. It echo'd the inputs, but not in the right position.

I tried looking for an answer, but couldn't really find one that was similar to mine. I found these questions and solution, tried them, and that also didn't work:
[How to pass arguments from add_settings_field() to the callback function?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/how-to-pass-arguments-from-add-settings-field-to-the-callback-function)
and
[Add_settings_field() parameterizing callback?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17710/add-settings-field-parameterizing-callback)

And for clarification, my `SettingsLayout.php` is build like this:

```php
<form  method="post"  action="options.php"  id="iw_form_<?php  echo  $i?>">
    <?php
        settings_fields( "iw_"  .  $i );
        do_settings_sections(  "info_kreis_bearbeiten"  );
        submit_button( $text  =  NULL,  $type  =  "primary",  $name  =  "submit_"  .  $i );
    ?>
</form>
```

`$i` is the same as `$n`.

## What to do?

I have run out of options to try. At least of options, I know of. If anyone has any kind of solution, I would be HAPPY to hear them. I also explained myself as best as I could.

### Edit

Which I forgot to mention, inside my  `foreach()`  I also echoed  `field["id"]`  to see if that works, and it does echo the right ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could see, the problem is not with the field callback, but it's the *section ID* whereby you're setting it to `default` — see `$field["section"] = 'default'` below:

```php
// In the foreach in AddSettings.php
add_settings_field( $field["id"], $field["title"], isset( $field["callback"] ) ? $field["callback"] : "", $field["page"], $field["section"] = 'default', $field["args"] = array() );
```

So you'd only to correct that (typo?) and the fields would show up as expected, or that the field callback would run properly. And you should also correct the `$field["args"] = array()`..

Comment: I can't believe that was the problem. I removed ``= 'default'`` from the code and it shows up. I am so relieved.  
Now I am trying to loop it, hopefully, that will work.